# Flag a previous row using partition and lag (SQL)

Tags: sql, teradata

I need help creating a flag when a value decrease, however, the flag must occur in the previous row:

Example

[image]

my current query:

```
 select  account, amount case when amount < lag(amount) over (partition by account order by start_date ) and 
(start_date = lag(end_date+1) over (partition by account order by start_date))
then 1 else 0 end as flag, start_date, end_date
from table
```

the result I get:

[image]

the result I want:

[image]

I just want to flag the previous row instead of the current, feels fairly simple but I can't find the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please don't post images of data

Comment: Looks like you can just use lead() instead of lag() right?

Comment: yes, actually I tried earlier but I guess I messed up cause it is working now.

Answer (score -1):

```
   select  account, amount case when amount > lead(amount) over (partition by account order by start_date ) and 
    (end_date+1 = lead(start_date) over (partition by account order by start_date))
    then 1 else 0 end as flag, start_date, end_date
    from table
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves this issue. Code-only answer are not good answers